# React Native ListView row not re-rendering after state change

Tags: react-native

React Native ListView: Rows are not re-rendering after datasource state has changed.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```js
render(): {
  return <ListView
    dataSource={this.state.DS}
    renderRow={this.renderRow}/>
}

renderRow(item): {
  return <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.handlePress(item)}>
    {this.renderButton(item.prop1)} 
    </TouchableOpacity>
}

renderButton(prop1): {
  if (prop1 == true) {
    return <Text> Active </Text>
  } else {
    return <Text> Inactive </Text>
  }
}

handlePress(item): {
  **Change the prop1 of *item* in an array (clone of dataSource), then**
  this.setState({
    DS: this.state.DS.cloneWithRows(arrayFromAbove)
  })
}
```

According to Facebook's example, ListView is supposed to rerender every time data source is changed. Is it because I'm only changing a property of an item in data source? It seems like renderRow function is not re-rendering, but render() function is from datasource change.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set the `datasource` in the `getInitialState` function. Then, change the datasource by calling `this.setState({})` and passing in the new datasource. It looks like you may have been on the right track above, but I have set up a working example of **changing** the **ListView** datasource [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/r3bzOQ) . I hope this helps

https://rnplay.org/apps/r3bzOQ

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion/example! I've definitely done the same in my project. I believe the problem is that ListView does not re-render a row when the datasource is an array of objects and just a property of one object is changed. Console tells me that the property of one object in data source has indeed changed, but ListView does recognize it and does not rerender the changed row. Do you have a possible workaround for this?

Comment: It will rerender if you call this.setState. Can you duplicate the issue here: https://rnplay.org/apps/Dw08-g.

Comment: Definitely, it is duplicated here (https://rnplay.org/apps/1-sNcQ). Looks like datasource is changing but renderRow function is not running. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I ended up setting the initial state of the DS to an empty array, then setting the state of data to the data. Then, on the click function, mutating the data, then resetting the state, which worked pretty nicely, removing the need to reset the DS state. Let me know if this helps, and I'll edit my above answer with this link. https://rnplay.org/apps/r3bzOQ

Answer (score 7):

react is smart enough to detect changes in dataSource and if the list should be re-rendered. If you want to update listView, create new objects instead of updating the properties of existing objects.
The code would look something like this:

```js
let newArray = this._rows.slice();
newArray[rowID] = {
  ...this._rows[rowID],
  newPropState: true,
};
this._rows = newArray;

let newDataSource = this.ds.cloneWithRows(newArray);
this.setState({
  dataSource: newDataSource
});
```

You can read more about similar [issue on Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4104)